# Convert JavaScript Date from one timezone to the other?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs, dst

I'm receiving a date from the server in a string format (ISO 8601) with timezone specification, e.g.: `2014-12-14T21:00:00+0300`.

I need to convert it to a standard JavaScript `Date` object in the specific timezone, e.g. `Europe/Moscow` with regards to DST and such.

I've tried to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) with [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) to achieve this, but to no avail.

#### Example

```
var date = '2014-12-14T21:00:00+0300';
var timezone = 'Europe/Moscow';

var momentDate = moment.tz(date, timezone);
var jsDate = momentDate.toDate();

console.log(
    date,
    momentDate.format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ'),
    jsDate
);
```

The `jsDate` is still in the local timezone of the browser (OS).

How do I cast JavaScript Date object to another timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timezones are merely a *presentation* issue.

The `Date` object will always be in UTC, but your browser will typically adjust the output when you convert it to a string into the local timezone.

If you wish to present the variable `jsDate` as a string represented in a *different* timezone then you must also use something like moment to perform that conversion.

Comment: So the browser will always treat a Date object in it's local (OS) timezone? No way to change that? The problem is that I need to feed this date object to a third-party component and I want it to format date in a specific timezone.

Comment: No, it'll always _store_ it in UTC, but it'll _display_ it in the local TZ.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like timezone handling/date formatting should be implemented on the third-party component level then.

Comment: @SlavaFominII that would be my take on it, yes.

Comment: @SlavaFominII - If you're using moment, then let it do the formatting.  Alnitak is correct - Once you go back to a `Date` object, you revert control back to the browser - which will always use the local time zone.

Answer (score 0):

As **@Alnitak** said this is a strictly presentation problem. All JavaScript dates are internally stored in the UTC format and manipulated in the local timezone of the browser (OS). The only place where target timezone is coming into action is when you converting Date object to a string in order to show it to a user. All dates will be formatted according to a local timezone of the each individual user.

However, if you want to format dates in some specific timezone (for example when your users are in the New York and you want to show dates in Moscow) you will have to use more advanced formatting utilities like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) and [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/).

When you control all the date formatting in your application - that can be easily implemented. However, when you need to relay this functionality to some third-party component that doesn't care about timezones and such (like some DatePicker component) it can become pretty ugly.

The only practical solution I've found to overcome this issue is to create a standard `Date` object that is pretending to be in local timezone of the user. Here's the function, that you can use:

```javascript
/**
 * Returns standard Date from Moment.js date as if it was in local timezone.
 * Use getMoment() method of the result to get proper Moment.js date back.
 *
 * @param {object} momentDate
 *
 * @returns {Date}
 */
function momentAsLocalDate(momentDate) {

    var origOffset = momentDate.format('ZZ');
    var localOffset = moment().format('ZZ');

    // Creating a standard date as if date was in current browser TZ.
    var stdDate = new Date(
        // Creating date from ISO:8601 format.
        momentDate.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss') + localOffset
    );

    stdDate.getMoment = function() {

        function pad(number) {
            if (number < 10) {
                return '0' + number;
            }
            return number;
        }

        // String in ISO:8601 format.
        var dateString =
            this.getFullYear() +
            '-' + pad(this.getMonth() + 1) +
            '-' + pad(this.getDate())      +
            'T' + pad(this.getHours())     +
            ':' + pad(this.getMinutes())   +
            ':' + pad(this.getSeconds())   +
            origOffset
        ;

        // Creating a new moment from date string.
        var momentDate = moment(dateString);

        // Setting original timezone.
        momentDate.zone(origOffset);

        return momentDate;
    };

    return stdDate;
}
```

The usage of this function can be demonstrated with the following simple test:

```javascript
/**
 * A stupid third-party component that doesn't care about timezones.
 *
 * @param {Date} inputDate
 */
var thirdPartyComponent = function(inputDate) {

    // Showing date to a user.
    console.log('Here is the date: ' + inputDate);

    // Changing the date.
    inputDate.setHours(17, 30);

};

var momentDate = moment('2014-12-14T21:00:00+03:00').zone('+03:00');

console.log('Original Moment Date', momentDate.format());

var stdDate = momentAsLocalDate(momentDate);

console.log('Converted Local Date', stdDate);

thirdPartyComponent(stdDate);

console.log('Changed Local Date', stdDate);

console.log('Converted Moment Date', stdDate.getMoment().format());
```

You will get the following result in the console:

```
Original Moment Date 2014-12-14T21:00:00+03:00
Converted Local Date Sun Dec 14 2014 21:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
Here is the date: Sun Dec 14 2014 21:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
Changed Local Date Sun Dec 14 2014 17:30:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
Converted Moment Date 2014-12-14T17:30:00+03:00
```

I would highly recommend not to use this approach in practice if you can do so. The better course of action is to rewrite the component to support timezones or to switch to a better component. However, if there is no other options, use it very carefully and at your own risk.

If there are better solutions, or this example can be improved - please let me know.

Cheers!

Comment: Nice try, but this isn't a great idea in general.  You're getting `localOffset` from the *current* date.  That might not be the correct offset at all for the date being manipulated. Remember about daylight saving time, and that it is implemented *differently* for different time zones.  The local DST rules may or may not align with the target time zone.  Ultimately, the function here doesn't add much value over what's already built in to moment and moment-timezone.  (intended as constructive criticism only)